# TDS install the sitecore connector for each project in my solution

Tags: helix, tds

I am using a Helix/Habitat-inspired setup in which the Sitecore items of my solution is split into a number of smaller projects in the different layers (Foundation, Features and project). Currently we have +50 smaller TDS projects.

My issue is that it seems that TDS installs its connector for each project when i I build, which slows the build process a lot. As the connector is the same for all projects, and the Sitecore Access Guid is the same, I would expect the connector to only be installed once.

Do any of you have experience in optimizing the build process with regards to TDS?

*Note: I have a TdsGlobal.config file which controls my TDS projects and currently it contains the following settings:*

```
<!-- Deployment Properties -->
<SitecoreWebUrl>http://local.dev</SitecoreWebUrl>
<SitecoreDeployFolder>C:\Websites\local.dev\Website</SitecoreDeployFolder>
<RecursiveDeployAction>SitecoreRecycle</RecursiveDeployAction>
<InstallSitecoreConnector>True</InstallSitecoreConnector>
<DisableFileDeployment>False</DisableFileDeployment>
<SitecoreAccessGuid>b0c833d0-1061-4c83-9c84-f2418527863a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of TDS are you using? Though I won't argue that TDS can be a build performance bottle neck, version 5.5+ doesn't install the connector if one of the same version is found. See release notes for 5.5:

http://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Download

Comment: Hi @alex-tselevic. We were using the 5.1 release by mistake and upgrading it seems to have fixed the issue. However the deploy is still rather slow in my opinion :-)

Comment: I have 5.6 installed and i am still seeing "Install Connector" for every TDS project.  Really unneeded overhead.